# Convert String array to Char array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm extremely stuck here.
How would I convert a String array to a Char array?

I know of:

```
char[] myCharArray = myStringArray.toCharArray();
```

But obviously that doesn't work.

How would I do this?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what exactly you want to do? As is, it's hard to tell.

Comment: You're thinking C and `char*` strings.  Java doesn't work that way.  You'd have to have a `char[][]` array to convert to from a string array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a 2d/jagged array.

```
char[][] char2dArray = new char[myStringArray.length()][];

for ( int i=0; i < myStringArray.length(); i++) {
    char2dArray[i] = myStringArray[i].toCharArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to grab all the chars from all the strings in a single char array, if that's what you meant with the question:

```
String[] strArray = {"ab", "cd", "ef"};

int count = 0;
for (String str : strArray) {
    count += str.length();
}
char[] charArray = new char[count];

int i = 0;
for (String str : strArray) {
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        charArray[i++] = c;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charArray));
=> [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

Comment: I'll give you +1 if you use some curlies =)

Comment: @Centril it's a deal! you just got yourself 6 brand-new curlies

Comment: System.arraycopy might be faster than those character by character copies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your String array converting every string in the string array to a char and then add that new char to your char array.

Comment: How do you convert a `String` to a `char`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a myStringArray is an array of Strings you would have to first iterate through this array extracting each individual String before converting the String to an array of chars.

for example

```
 for (String str : myStringArray) {
 {
   char[] myCharArray = myStringArray.toCharArray();
   // do something with myCharArray 
 }
```